# Issue with tunnel-ssh npm for ssh connection to mongo through mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to establish a connection to remote mongo server through ssh tunnel using mongoose

The implementation code is:

```
import tunnel from 'tunnel-ssh';

const config = {
    username: 'username',
    Password: 'password',
    host: process.env.SSH_SERVER, //192.168.9.104
    port: 22,
    dstHost: process.env.DESTINATION_SERVER, //192.168.9.104
    dstPort: process.env.DESTINATION_PORT, //27017
    localHost: '127.0.0.1',
    localPort: 27017
};
```

this is the config that i have created while the connection is as follows:

```
class DB {
    initDB() {
        tunnel(config, (error, server) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('SSH connection error: ' + error);
            }
            const url = 'mongodb://' + process.env.MONGO_URL; //localhost:27017/DBname
            mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
            mongoose.plugin(toJson);
            mongoose.plugin(setProperties);

            var db = mongoose.connection;
            db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection error:'));
            db.once('open', function() {
                console.log('DB connection successful');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

When the function `initDB()` is invoked the following error pops up

```
SSH connection error: ConfigError: host not set

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ConfigError: host not set
```

The host is already set but this error seems to be somewhere in the config part but I doesnt seem to single out to the exact reason

Answer (score 0):

your "host" property at "config" var isn't defined. try using hard coded value instead of env var, if it works it means process can't read env vars which might be caused since you R not importing dotenv module